# libfuse: How should I set fuse(8) options internally?

Tags: c, fuse

I want to set `default_permissions` option as default.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html

> default_permissions
>
> ...
>
> Filesystems that do not implement any permission checking
>   should generally add this option internally.

The simplest way is adding `-o default_permissions` to `argv` and pass it to `fuse_main`, like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char **new_argv = malloc(sizeof(char *)*(argc+3));
  memcpy(new_argv, argv, sizeof(char *)*argc);
  new_argv[argc] = "-o";
  new_argv[argc+1] = "default_permissions";
  new_argv[argc+2] = NULL;

  return fuse_main(argc+2, new_argv, &hello_oper, NULL);
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the best way... It looks ugly.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hard-coding 64 as the size of argv is not a good idea. A better idea would be to malloc (argc + 3), then set the new elements to `-o`, `default_permissions`, and `NULL`.

Comment: @PaulBelanger Thank you for the feedback! I fixed :)